# CSS hover transition is not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have a div. I want to make border on this div on hover effect. And this border should come with transition effect. it is working fine. But my problem is when I move mouse from the div at this time border goes directly without any transition effect.
here is my div

```css
.pending:hover{
     -webkit-transition: border .35s ease-in-out;
     transition: border .35s ease-in-out;
     border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pending">
   <h2>this is title </h2>
   <button>Menu</button>
   <button>Menu</button>
   <button>Menu</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the transitions just on the `.pending` class and a white border and then create the red border on the hover:

```css
.pending {
  -webkit-transition: border .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: border .35s ease-in-out;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.pending:hover {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pending">
  <h2>this is title </h2>
  <button>Menu</button>
  <button>Menu</button>
  <button>Menu</button>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thats great, please accept the answer when you can :)

Answer (score 6):

This happens because you apply the transition effect to a hover state only. As soon as the hover state is gone, the transition itself is also gone. In addition, no border style is specified, so there is no state to transition to.

The below snippet should demonstrate:

```css
.pending {
  border: 0px solid red;
  -webkit-transition: border .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: border .35s ease-in-out;
}

.pending:hover{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pending">
  <h2>this is title</h2>
  <button>Menu</button>
  <button>Menu</button>
  <button>Menu</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Fokrule the transition from the :hover state can be removed ;)